# Java how to get a reference to an object that exposes `Math`'s static methods?

Tags: java

Imagine I have a

```
public void doStuff(Object foo) {
  ...
}
```

Method (actually I am using graalvm and passing in host objects)

I can't call it with `java.lang.Math`,

```
doStuff(Math);
```

errors, and `doStuff(new Math())` also errors (Frustratingly? Uselessly?) because the constructor is private.

I just want a way to have a reference to an object that exposes exactly the same methods as `java.lang.Math` exposes.

Comment: most of Math's methods are static the cannon be accessed by object  and that has a private constructor as you should not create a object of that class to have same method you need to make them . do you want an example of how to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to abstract the use of `java.lang.Math` behind an interface?

Comment: This might be an XY problem. Why do you feel you need to pass around the Math class?

Comment: You can have a method, `public void doStuff(Math math)` but because Math uses static methods, you'll just be referencing the original static methods.

Comment: I think a little more context would be helpful. *Why* do you need that?

Comment: @NomadMaker to give it to a JS graalvm context, so that the JS can use it.

Comment: @QBrute to give it to a JS graalvm context, so that the JS can use `Math.whatever`.

Comment: @matt which is exactly what I want

Comment: @minseong I don't understand what you want. You could create an interface `MathInterface` where all of the methods have a default implementation using the Math.xyz version. Then you can pass around MathInterface's and override the methods that you want overridden.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  It can't be instantiated.  But you can pass method references or lambdas of it's methods (although this example is somewhat contrived and not of much use).

```
double dmax = getMaximum(Math::max, 20., 40.);
int imax = getMaximum(Math::max, 14, 80);

System.out.println(dmax);
System.out.println(imax);
```

Prints

```
40.0
80
```

The method

```
public static <T> T getMaximum(BinaryOperator<T> op, T a, T b) {
        return op.apply(a,b);
}
```

Comment: It seems to be possible to instantiate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65938087/3310334

Comment: I was referring to adhering to good coding practices and not violating the principals of encapsulation.  Did you notice the nasty red warning when you do this?  And if a security manager was running and properly configured you would not be able to do it.  Private fields and constructors are meant to be private for a reason.

Comment: I get that it is really bad coding style, but why is it insecure?

Comment: In this case it probably isn't insecure.  But being able to access private fields and such can have security consequences.